# Logic App JSON composition converted JSON value as string

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am creating a logic app where I use azure function to return json back. Then I need to compose the JSON with return value plus other properties which eventually I will store in CosmosDB. I get the response correctly from function as array however when I compose that who is converted as string after composition. Due this it is storing as string in DB than a document . Appreciate your support.
**Current** output
{
"id": "D",
"studydate": "DD",
"studydescription": "DD",
"studyname": "D",
"/csdm/table1.csv": "[{"No":"1","Name":"Ananda","Date":"Krishna","Description\r":"1111\r"},{"No":"2","Name":"Test2","Date":"Test2","Description\r":"2222\r"},{"No":"3","Name":"Test3","Date":"Test3","Description\r":"3333"}]"
}
[image]

**Expected output**

"id": "D",
"studydate": "DD",
"studydescription": "DD",
"studyname": "D",
"/csdm/table1.csv":[
{
"No": "1",
"Name": "Ananda",
"Date": "Krishna",
"Description\r": "1111\r"
},
{
"No": "2",
"Name": "Test2",
"Date": "Test2",
"Description\r": "2222\r"
}

**Below is Azure function code:**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
const filecontents = req.body
const filename= req.query.filename
context.log(req.body)
const splitfilecontents = filecontents.split("\n")
const splitheader = splitfilecontents[0].split(",")
const totalrows = splitfilecontents.length
context.log(splitfilecontents)
let ret=[]
let data=[]

header=[]

itemjson= []
finaljson={}

context.log("header"+splitfilecontents[0])
context.log("header Length"+splitfilecontents[0].length)
const headerrow= splitfilecontents[0].split(",")
context.log("Headers Total"+headerrow)
 for (let i=1, len=splitfilecontents.length; i<len;i++)
 {
    data = splitfilecontents[i].split(",")
    context.log("Row Data"+data)
    item = {}
    for (let j=0,len2=headerrow.length;j<len2;j++)
     {
        
        item[headerrow[j]] = data[j]
        context.log("row"+i+"column"+j+"Data"+item[headerrow[j]])
        
     }
     itemjson.push(item)
     context.log("item"+i+"Data"+item[headerrow[0]])
 }
finaljson=JSON.stringify(itemjson)
finaljson2=JSON.stringify(finaljson)
finaljson3=JSON.stringify(finaljson2)
context.log(finaljson)


context.log("final data"+finaljson.length)





context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: itemjson
};
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by adding below code in my azure function response.

````
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: finaljson,
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }```
````